# Product grid is not loading in admin, - Error: Unresponsive script

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, jquery, product-grid

The product grid is not loading properly in the backend when logged in as the Administrator. I get an error of `unresponsive script`.

But if I login to the backend with another user (personal user) the product grid loads successfully.

[image]
Can anyone suggest why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have created some custom attributes. Can you go to the database and clear all entries from ui_bookmarks table? This should fix the issue if it is because of previously applied filter. It could also be because this perticular is trying to load many many rows. In that case coat local storage. Let me know

Comment: Yes, problem is loading in many rows. but can i resolve this.

Comment: There is iteration limit that browser imposes on JavaScript. How many rows are you loading? Did clearing local storage and ui bookmarks solve the issue. You might not even face this issue in chrome.

Comment: I have check after clearing ui_bookmarks table. But its not working. I open it in private window also but its not working. I think product listing  rows count for particular admin user save somewhere in database. Problem of loading many row is correct i also notice this.

Comment: In admin user table user meta data is set. You can clear that.

Comment: user meta data in which table??

Comment: Alright after clearing ui_bookmarks loggout immidietly by clearing  admin_user_session table and var folder